# Parse text file to object

Tags: java

I have few same type text files.

```
name: Michel;
race: Man;
age: 44;
```

How to parse them values to List Characters

```
public class Character {

    private String name;
    private String race;
    private String age;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to parse a text file in Java, then the rest should be easy

Comment: Are you facing any specific problem while reading each line and splitting on `:` or removing `;`?

Comment: Note that there is already a standard Java class named `java.lang.Character`. Using the same name `Character` can easily lead to confusing error messages; it's better to give your class a different name.

Comment: Your text file is similar to YAML. If you want to use that format, there are some great libraries. Find them https://yaml.org/. Otherwise, if the format dictates that each line is new data, you can just use `BufferedReader` or `Scanner` to read line by line. Or you can read the whole content and split by `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a BufferedReader, FileReader or Scanner object to read txt files in Java. It depends on which you'd like to use for it's functions.

You can use them to iterate trough lines in the txt file and you can put that read content in a String. Then you can assign that stringvalue to your objectvariables.

A quick google brought me to this website which explains the methods complete with code examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/

Answer (score 0):

Here add one character with change name class

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(path))));
        String line;
        String name = null;
        String race = null;
        String age = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("name:")) {
                    name = line.substring(6, line.length() - 1);
            }
            if (line.contains("race:")) {
                    race = line.substring(6, line.length() - 1);
            }
            if (line.contains("age:")) {
                    age = line.substring(5, line.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(name);
        person.setRace(race);
        person.setAge(age);
        personList.add(person);
        return personList;
```